# A question about the proof of Hoeffding's inequality

Tags: probability, inequality

Why the Inequality satisfies?

According to my knowledge, the upper bound is taken when $X_i$ is a quasi-Bernoulli.

But the result was so complex that I can't find any relationship with the right side.

$$e^{-s t} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \mathrm{E}\left[e^{s\left(X_{i}-\mathrm{E}\left[X_{i}\right]\right)}\right]\leq e^{-s t} \prod_{i=1}^{n} e^{\frac{s^{2}\left(b_{i}-a_{i}\right)^{2}}{8}}$$

Wish someone to tell me, THANKS!

Comment: Please clarify what you want. Do you want an example that the inequality is in fact an equality? Or something else?

Comment: I want to know how did we got the inequality.